# Can I subscribe to an RSS feed of my favorite questions?

Tags: support, feed

Is it possible to subscribe to the RSS feed of my favorite questions on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this feed:

> `http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/{ID}/favorites?body=true`

...where **{ID}** is your user ID for StackOverflow.

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: This link does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: @shantanuo: There, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

there is a question feed at the bottom right of the any question page you can subscribe to.

Comment: looking for feed of favorite questionS and not one question :)

Comment: @shan: See my answer.