# Is there a way to get notification when my favourite question gets an answer?

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications

SO has a high traffic and within 5 minutes the question in the main page changes. So suppose a question is posted and I liked the question. So is there a way I can get notification when an answer is posted to the question? The only possible way now present is to mark the question as "my favourite" and I have to browse from my profile every now and then to see if an answer is posted to the question or not. This seems to me a rather tedious work because somebody can have a large number of favourite questions in his profile. To make SO more friendly I think we should have such a way that when an answer is posted to my favourite question, I should get a notification. After all, it is my favourite question and surely I would like to check out all the possible answers.

Comment: You can get an rss feed of a question's activity at the bottom of every question page. Also appears you can get ALL favorite questions' activity in a single rss feed [described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73172/can-i-subscribe-to-an-rss-feed-of-my-favorite-questions).